# XML-RPC: how to make login credentials accessible to procedure calls?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, rpc

Say my server exports the following procedure:

```
List listFiles(int userId);
```

I can't allow just any user to list files for a given user. They need to have authorization to do so.

My XML-RPC service uses basic auth to authenticate users.

What would be the recommended way to make the login credentials (the current user object) accessible to the procedure calls?

Comment: What XML-RPC server implementation are you using?

Comment: Apache XML-RPC -> http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution. The key is to subclass the RequestProcessorFactoryFactory and specify to the Handler that you wish to use your subclass.

http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/server/RequestProcessorFactoryFactory.RequestSpecificProcessorFactoryFactory.html

```
protected java.lang.Object getRequestProcessor(java.lang.Class pClass,
                                               XmlRpcRequest pRequest)
                                        throws XmlRpcException
```

*Subclasses may override this method for request specific configuration. A typical subclass will look like this:*

```
   public class MyRequestProcessorFactoryFactory
           extends RequestProcessorFactoryFactory.RequestSpecificProcessorFactoryFactory {
       protected Object getRequestProcessor(Class pClass, XmlRpcRequest pRequest) {
           Object result = super.getRequestProcessor(pClass, pRequest);
           // Configure the object here
           ...
           return result;
       }
   }
```

*Parameters:
pRequest - The request object.
Throws:
XmlRpcException*

Here's an example telling the default handler to use your Factory:

```
  public class EchoServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      WebServer webServer = new WebServer(8080);
      XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = webServer.getXmlRpcServer();
      PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
      EchoService echo = new EchoServiceImpl();
      phm.setRequestProcessorFactoryFactory(new MyRequestProcessorFactoryFactory());
      phm.setVoidMethodEnabled(true);
      phm.addHandler(EchoService.class.getName(), EchoService.class);
      xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);

      XmlRpcServerConfigImpl serverConfig = (XmlRpcServerConfigImpl) xmlRpcServer.getConfig();
      serverConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
      serverConfig.setContentLengthOptional(false);
      webServer.start();
    }
  }
```

So to answer my original question, I would create a RequestProcessorFactoryFactory as folows:

```
   public class MyRequestProcessorFactoryFactory
           extends RequestProcessorFactoryFactory.RequestSpecificProcessorFactoryFactory {
       protected Object getRequestProcessor(Class pClass, XmlRpcRequest pRequest) {
           Object result = super.getRequestProcessor(pClass, pRequest);
           // Configure the object here
           ClassOfObjectBeingExposedViaXmlRpc obj = (ClassOfObjectBeingExposedViaXmlRpc) result;
           XmlRpcHttpRequestConfig httpRequest = (XmlRpcHttpRequestConfig) pRequest.getConfig();
           MyUserClass user = authenticateSomehow(httpRequest.getBasicUserName(), httpRequest.getBasicPassword());
           obj.setUser(user);
           return result;
       }
   }
```

Thus the XML-RPC exposed object will be able to reference the authenticated user and authorize methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own XmlRpcServlet subclass (see http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html section Basic Authentication for an example), you could stick the user credentials on a ThreadLocal (see http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use).